# loopback storage component afterRemote/beforeRemote hook destroyContainer not called from another model

Tags: node.js, cron, hook, loopbackjs, strongloop

**Problem**:

I have a cronjob in server.js started on startup to delete containers after a certain time. before I delete them though, I want to check if they are not marked as "not-to-be-deleted", realised via another "container meta" model (PersistedModel in DB) because I can't save metadata about containers in the container model (datasource is filesystem, so only f.stat metadata is available).
Now when the Containers are deleted from the API Explorer by directly calling Container.destroyContainer(name), the `beforeRemote("destroyContainer")` hook is called, but not the `afterRemote("destroyContainer")` hook.

When I delete the containers via cronjob however, even though the same method is called, none of the remote method hooks are called.

**What I tried:**

Wrapping it in a promise/promises or just using the callback as is made no difference, also afterRemote(**) and checking if the `ctx.methodString === "container.destroyContainer"` didn't help either.
Also when calling `Container.destroyContainer` from other models the before/afterRemote hooks of the container model were not called.

**What works and why do I need this:**

The deletion of the containers, filtering via another meta container models properties works fine, also when promisifying the callback-only methods of the loopback-component-storage API. I just need the hooks to work to delete related meta information after a container was deleted and/or do some checks before that.

--

Any help/hint is appreciated!

**Sourcecode:**

This is my cronjob (using the [kelektiv/node-cron package](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)) in `server.js` reduced to the necessary parts and got rid of the promises:

```
const CronJob = require( "cron" ).CronJob
boot( app, __dirname, ( err ) => {
  if ( err ) throw err
let Container = app.models.Container

const garbageCollectorJob = new CronJob({
  cronTime: "0 * * * * *", // runs every minute (test)
  onTick: function() {
    // first get all available containers
    Container.getContainers( ( err, deleteableContainers ) => {
    if ( err ) {
      throw err
    } else {
      deleteableContainers.map( ( container ) => {
        console.log( `deleted ${  container.name}` )
        Container.destroyContainer( container.name, ( err, result ) => {
          if ( err ) throw ( err )
          else console.log( "finished" )
          })
        })
      }
    })
  },
start: false,
})
// start the cronjob explicitely
garbageCollectorJob.start()

})
```

in `container.js` are my beforeRemote/afterRemote hooks:

```
Container.beforeRemote( "destroyContainer", ( ctx, unused, next ) => {
    console.log( "Container about to be deleted" )
    let container = ctx.req.params.container
    // this hook is not called before cronjob deletion or from another model, only when directly call (from API Explorer for example)
    next()
})

Container.afterRemote( "destroyContainer", ( ctx, affectedInstance, next ) => {
    console.log( "Container was deleted, now softdelete file metainfo, metacontainer, task, process, fileRef" )
    // this hook is not called after cronjob deletion
    next()
}
```

npm: 6.0.0
nodejs: 8.1.2
loopback: 3.20
loopback-component-storage: 3.3.1
os: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6